# JMeter, pass value between Thread Group

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

the situation I am studying is :

- *ThreadGroup1* (n-thread):

  - Sampler that generate and store in a UserDefinedVariable table a specific value (**prodId**, value different for each thread in the group).
- *ThreadGroup2* (n-thread):

  - Sampler that could be retrieve one of the *prodid*.

A little contraints: since n **prodids** are generated in the first group, I want each thread of the second group to get only one of the **prodids** (example Group2: Thread1 takes ProdID1, Thread2 takes ProdId2; I don't want thread1 and thread2 both take prodId1).
Anyone could help me? 
Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If you want to simply pass values between thread groups - go for [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination in 1st Thread Group like

   - to convert JMeter Variable into a thread-specific JMeter Property:

     ```
     ${__setProperty(prodId_${__threadNum},${prodId},)}
     ```
   - to read the value in 2nd Thread Group use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in conjunction with the aforementioned __threadNum() function :

     ```
     ${__P(prodId_${__threadNum},)}
     ```

   [image]
2. For more complex scenarios, like you'd like to hold on some thread execution in thread group 2 until some variable has some value or for implementing queue-like collection - go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: The thread numers generated in the ThreadGroup1 they are the same ones that will be generated in the ThreadGroup2?

Comment: Given you have the same number of threads - yes